# Android OpenSL ES crystal frequency

Tags: android, audio, android-ndk, opensl

we have an app with mobile audio clients written in low-level OpenSL ES to achieve low-latency input from microphone. Than we are sending 10ms frames encapsulated in UDP datagram to server.

On server we are doing some post-processing which is curucially dependent on aan assumption that frames from mobile clients comes in fixed intervals (eg. 10ms per frame), so we can align them.

It seems that internal crystal frequencies on mobile phones can vary a lot and due to this, we are getting perfect alignment on the beggining but poor alignment after few minutes.

I know, that ALSA on Linux can tell you exact frequency of the crystal - so you can correct your counts based on this. Unfortunatelly I don't know how to get this information in Android.

Thx for help

Answer (score 3):

The essence of the problem you face is that you have an ADC and a DAC on separate systems with different local oscillators.  You're presumably timing your packets against a 3rd (and possibly 4th) CPU clock.

The correct solution to this problem is some kind of [clock recovery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clock_recovery) algorithm.  To do this properly you need some means of accurately timestamping (e.g. to bit accuracy) transmitted packets, and then use a PLL to drive the clock-rate of the receiver's sample clock.   This is is precisely the approach that both IEEE1394 audio and MPEG2 Transport streams use.

Since probably can't do either of these things, your approach is most likely going to involve dropping or repeating samples (or even entire packets) periodically to keep your receive buffer from under- or over-flowing.

USB Audio has a similar lack of hardware support for clock recovery, and the approaches used there may be applicable to your situation.

Relying on the transmission and reception timing of network packets is a terrible idea.   The jitter on delivery times is horrendous - particularly with Wifi or cellular connections.   You'd be well advised to use not rely on it at all, and instead do as both IEEE1394 audio and MPEG 2 TS do, which is to decouple audio data transport from consumption using a model FIFO in which data is consumed at a constant rate and delivered to it in packets of unreliable timing.

As for ALSA, all it can do (unless if has an accurate external timing reference) is to measure the drift between the sample clock of the audio interface and the CPU's clock.  This does not yield 'the exact frequency' of anything as neither oscillator is likely to be accurate, and both may drift dependent on temperature.